# d3 button not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been going in circles and can't get this button to work. My intention is for the response_handler() function to be called when the button gets clicked. I can't figure out what the issue is. Attached is my js and html code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The frame work that I am using is d3.js and I have no prior experience with it. I am using it because of the psiturk framework.

```
var MNISTExperiment = function(){

var wordon, // time word is presented
    listening = false;

    var stims = [
    "http://joshmontague.com/images/mnist-2.png",
    "http://blog.otoro.net/assets/20160401/png/random01.png",
    "http://blog.otoro.net/assets/20160401/png/random07.png",
    ];


stims = _.shuffle(stims);

var button = d3.select("#next");
button.on("click", function(){
            response_handler();
    });

var next = function() {
    if (stims.length===0) {
        finish();
    }
    else {

        stim = stims.shift();

        d3.select('#photo').append('img')
        .attr('src',stim)
        .attr('width',300)                  
        .attr('height',300)


        // d3.select("#next").on("click", function() {
        //   response_handler();
        // });

        }   
}

var response_handler = function() {
    alert("Called");

    var keyCode = e.keyCode,
        response;

        var rt = new Date().getTime() - wordon;

        var radios = 0;

        d3.selectAll("input[name='1']").on("change", function(){
            radios=this.value;
        });

        psiTurk.recordTrialData({'phase':"TEST",
                                 'image':stim,
                                 'response_1':radios,
                                 'rt':rt}
                               );
        psiTurk.saveData();
        remove_image();
};

var remove_image = function() {
    stims = stims.slice(1);
};

var finish = function() {
    currentview = new Questionnaire();
};

// Load the stage.html snippet into the body of the page
psiTurk.showPage('stage.html');

next();
}
```

And here is my html code

```
<button type="button" id="next" value="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg continue"> 
Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: You have all of your D3 code wrapped in a function, but aren't calling the function. When I call the function, your `response_handler` function gets called. In your application, are you calling the function? For instance, if I write `MNISTExperiment();` at the very bottom of your JS code, the D3 button click works.